# bugged localhost address after running 'expo start --dev-client'

Tags: react-native, expo

I'm trying to start expo with: expo start --dev-client command but it's giving me a localhost address like so:  Metro waiting on project-name://expo-development-client/?url=http%3A%2F%2F192.168.1.10%3A8081 .
Why is this happening, and how do i fix it?
The address is normal while initializing with 'expo start'.
I'm using node v16.14.2 .

Comment: the error seems to have been caused by implementing this solution: https://github.com/expo/fyi/blob/main/setup-android-uri-scheme.md for "Linking is disabled because the client scheme cannot be resolved"